# How to append multiple text in text file

Tags: java

I want the results from 'name' and 'code' to be inserted into log.txt file, but if I run this program only the name results gets inserted into .txt file, I cannot see code results appending under name. If I do System.outprintln(name) & System.outprintln(code) I get results printed in console but its not being inserted in a file.Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt", true));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("text1")) {
                String[] splits = line.split("=");
                String name = splits[2];
                for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
                    out.println(name);

                }
            }

            if (line.contains("text2")) {
                String[] splits = line.split("=");
                String code = splits[2];
                for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++) {
                    out.println(code);

                }
            }
         out.close()            
          }
```

File looks like:

```
Name=111111111
Code=333,5555
Category-Warranty

Name=2222222
Code=111,22
Category-Warranty
```

Comment: What exactly is `br`? What lines does it contain? Does it contain any lines with the string "text2" in it? Besides that, you never assign the variables `name` and `code`. Are those two values part of the `line` you read from `br`?

Comment: I assume that the lines you read from `file` are `name=code`, where `name` and `code` are the values you want to write into `log.txt`, correct?

Comment: Have a look at my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this code. Does that work for you?

```
final String NAME = "name";
final String CODE = "code";

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt", true));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] splits = line.split("=");
    String key = splits[0];
    String value = splits[1];

    if (key.equals(NAME) || key.equals(CODE)) {
        out.println(value);
    }
}

out.close();
```

You have a couple of problems in your code:

- you never actually assign the variables `name` and `code`.
- you `close()` your `PrintWriter` inside the `while`-loop, that means you will have a problem if you read more than one line.

Comment: I get an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:" I think its because the split[0] and [1] it should be 1 for both i tried that too but same error

Comment: How do the strings you read look like? Do they always contain an `=` and is there always text both on the left and on the right side of it? Could you do us a favor and post an example how such a line would look like?

Comment: I like your answer better +1

Comment: Did some edits to my code. Do you understand how I try to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes now it works, if I place variable key & value it works. Thank you. But the only problem I see is with Category variable which contain - rather than =

Comment: Since it seems like you also have empty lines inside your file, you will get a problem with them, too, One solution would be to check the `length` of `splits` after splitting it by "=". If it is not equal 2, try and split it by "-". If the length is still not equal 2, you have an empty line and you should skip it and continue with the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this wouldn't work, without seeing more of what you are doing:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("log.txt", true));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains("=")) {
        if (line.contains("text1")) {
            String[] splits = line.split("=");
            if (splits.length >= 2) {
                out.println(splits[1]);
            }
        }
        if (line.contains("text2")) {
            String[] splits = line.split("=");
            if (splits.length >= 2) {
                out.println(splits[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the second if condition is satisfied i.e. the line String contains "text2".

Comment: when I do System.out.println() for text1 & text2, I get text printed in console but nothing is inserted into a file so there is defiantly something outputting in each if loop.